# #2003 - can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061) when I restart computer

Tags: appserver

I have a strange problem.

I install appServ successfully.

It can run after I installing it.

But it shows **#2003 - can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061)** when I restart my computer.

But I reinstall appServ, it can run successfully again.

I don't know why...

Could you give me some advices.

Thanks a lot !

*Notes:*

*appServ v2.5.10*

*windows XP*

Comment: Does your appServ start automatically after you restart your computer?

Comment: check the services tab under task manager to see if your mysql service is running?

Comment: I don't make any setting, but it can execute normally.
I think it might be MIS made some settings.
Thank you for giving me some advices.